# Como faço para pegar o valor de uma checkbox selecionada na mainActivity3 e 4 e mostrar esse item selecionado em um textView na main Activity1?

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade onde tenho q desenvolver um aplicativo para pedidos em um bar, ja criei 5 activity aonde a primeira e uma tela inicial e as outras telas de pedidos com checkbox, como faço para pegar os itens selecionados nas checkbox de todas main activity e mostra-los na mainactivity1? E tambem como faço para determinar um "preço" para cada checkbox onde na ultima activity eu possa mostrar o valor total de todas checkbox selecionadas?

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o valor do checkbox, você verifica se este está marcado e atribui um valor de referência, ex: [x] Cerveja:

```
   String valores;
   if(cerveja.isChecked()){
      valores += "1";
   }
```

Pq aí se tiver outro check vc vai adicionando os valores, mas aí você fala: Como esse 1 pode identificar que cerveja estava marcado, como tem mais checkbox a string pode ficar : valores = "12354"; então como cada valor representa um item, você faz:

```
  //Isso aqui na outra activity
  if(valores.contais("1")){
     //cerveja tava marcado
  }
```

Mas caso queira pegar o text do checkbox vc faz:

```
 String valor = checkbox.getText().toString();
```

Para passar valores entre activitys vc usa isso:

```
 Intent it = new Intent(context, proximaAcitivy.class);
          //Cada chave deve ser unica
          it.putExtra("chave", valor);
          startActivity(it);
```

Na outra activity para recuperar vc faz:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String text = intent.getStringExtra("chave");

 }
```

Sobre os preços, a cada verificação de qual checkbox está marcado, vc salva os valores e passa para outra activity e o soma com o próximo valor, faz o msm na próxima até chegar na última